# It is possible to change text color to linear-gradient on ionic?

Tags: text, colors, linear-gradients, ionic3

I know how to use the linear-gradient color for backgrounds, but it is possible to do the same for the color of the text?

Thank you

Comment: This solve my problem

background: -webkit-linear-gradient(50deg,#4ba9fc,#31dab4);
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution

```
 .toolbar-title{
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(30deg,#4ba9fc,#31dab4);
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
    //color: #fff;
    font-size: 3em;
    margin-top: 25px;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: "Lobster 1.4 Regular";
```